# How to get the next page on spring pagination

Tags: java, spring, pagination

I have a resource in my service with pagination and I would like to know how could I process the next request to get the second page.

Here is the java resource:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/partner/codes")
public Page<String> getCodes(@PageableDefault(size = 5) Pageable pageable) {
    final List<String> userIds = service.getIds();
    int start = pageable.getOffset();
    int end = (start + pageable.getPageSize()) > userIds.size() ? userIds.size() : (start + pageable.getPageSize());

    return new PageImpl<String>(userIds.subList(start, end), pageable, userIds.size());
}
```

And the response the response with 5 results:

```
{  
  "content":[  
    "4a136aa6-00d4-44f0-bb48-d192fd8bc010",
    "bebebaf2-b881-4733-8a65-1ecf80b5192e",
    "1a0f9d07-1393-48a8-8883-37d87681e84b",
    "d2580fdc-db6c-4fa3-89d4-2b52898a20bf",
    "2c90e683-4ed4-45a4-b70b-614a3339670b"
   ],
   "last":false,
   "totalPages":3,
   "totalElements":57,
   "size":20,
   "number":0,
   "sort":null,
   "numberOfElements":20,
   "first":true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, as there was nothing explicit in the documentation, I hadn't noticed that just passing the parameters in the query string.

```
?page=2&size=20
```

And the client should create the rule using the response message.